# How to prevent non members from directly accessing private content with PHP

Tags: php, apache, security, password-protection

I am aware of the .htaccess Apache method of protecting folders from non members but am wondering how it can be done with PHP only.

Checking for session variables can protect php pages but direct access to photos and or pdfs seem to sometimes be overlooked. For example if I copy a direct link to a photo from facebook, logout, then direct my browser to the url of the photo it shows no problem.

How to sites like Rapidshare protect against direct access to their content?

I know there's a way to set variables in Apache. Maybe there's a way to check for session variables with Apache?

Comment: If it's in a web accessible area PHP can't protect it

Comment: In the content folders you can `deny from all` and then use a php script to open and output the file directly to the browser for access to them for allowed users. (I believe those sites rewrite to a script to make it look like direct access)

Comment: @Jon - But that's not a PHP method which is what they're looking for

Comment: Rapidshare and the like don't offer direct access to their content. They use download scripts.

Comment: @JohnConde True, but if rewriting what looks like `direct access` in the `.htaccess` to a PHP script, and storing the content in a directory where access is denied, it would be the type of solution he is looking for (I believe). ^^

Comment: yes @Jon a solution that lets me authenticate access with only PHP is what im after. Im good setting up Apache however it needs to be.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario sounds like a download script is what im after...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the questions and comments, it seems that you are after URLs that look like direct access, but pass through a PHP script to allow for authorization to download them.  I don't know your current directory structure, so I'm going to make one up for this answer's test case - albeit a small listing:

```
public-html/
    content/        <- where the actual files are
        .htaccess   <- to deny access to the directory
    .htaccess       <- the one created here
    download.php    <- download script
```

From this, we are going to assume all the files are located in `/content` and the "direct link" will look like it is going to `/file`

The `/content/.htaccess`:

```
deny from all
```

The next one with the note that the first `RewriteRule` is so that normal files that already exist won't be overwritten, and the previous `.htaccess` prevent files in that directory from being accessed.  If you have an `.htaccess` that you are using already, the important rule is the last one, and it stops processing if it matches, so place it accordingly in your existing `.htaccess`.

`/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

    RewriteRule ^file/(.+)$ download.php?file=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

With that in place, it will look like direct access to a file if going to `/file/myDocument.pdf`, and it will be sent to the script like `download.php?file=myDocument.pdf`.

From there, it is a matter of creating the download script to use.  The one I am posting is a modified version of one from [Armand Niculescu found here](http://www.richnetapps.com/php-download-script-with-resume-option/).  I am only posting the relevant parts here ([the entirety can be found on PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/w7Hsd7tQ) where you can modify the parts posted here to fit your needs):

```
/******************************
 * PERFORM AUTHORIZATION HERE *
 *   The following is added   *
 ******************************/
if($_SESSION['validated'] !== true) {
    //Not authorized to download, send header and exit
    header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
    exit;
}
```

I have also made another minor edit for the correct file path 8 lines down:

```
$file_path  = './content/' . $file_name;
```

And that concludes this small example of how to get a working download script and making it look like direct file access.

Comment: In your edited version you're missing `session_start()` at the top of the script.

Answer (score 2):

From your question I get that you already know how to protect folders from direct access and also how to protect php scripts. So what you need is a protected php script providing indirect access to the files (as was already mentioned in the comments).

When creating this download script you should remember some important details:

- provide the mime type. In many cases `header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream")` is sufficient, though
- tell the client to download the file (instead of displaying it) and provide a filename: `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($path) . '"')`
- provide the file size: `header("Content-Length: " . filesize($path));`
- to avoid problems with large files you should use something like the following instead of `readfile`:

  ```
  $file = fopen($path, 'r');
  flush(); 
    while (!feof($file)) { 
    print(fread($file, 4096)); 
    flush(); 
  }
  fclose($file);
  ```

Comment: Please read the 'Notes' on [`readfile`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) -> "readfile() will not present any memory issues, even when sending large files, on its own.".  Also the [Common pitfalls of handling file downloads in PHP](http://www.richnetapps.com/the-right-way-to-handle-file-downloads-in-php/)